# swift: create glare button animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have button in my project. I want to add glare animation to my button like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And remove animation if user tapped on button.

How to add animation?

Comment: I don't think we can add such kind of animation to a button, rather you can take a image with such animation for example image posted above. And set it within the UIButton

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an effect like this by adding a lighter version of the buttons content to a `CALayer` then masking that layer and animating the mask. For example:

```
extension UIButton {

    func flash() {
        // Take as snapshot of the button and render as a template
        let snapshot = self.snapshot?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: snapshot)
        // Add it image view and render close to white
        imageView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        guard let image = imageView.snapshot  else { return }
        let width = image.size.width
        let height = image.size.height
        // Create CALayer and add light content to it
        let shineLayer = CALayer()
        shineLayer.contents = image.cgImage
        shineLayer.frame = bounds

        // create CAGradientLayer that will act as mask clear = not shown, opaque = rendered
        // Adjust gradient to increase width and angle of highlight
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor,
                                UIColor.clear.cgColor,
                                UIColor.black.cgColor,
                                UIColor.clear.cgColor,
                                UIColor.clear.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.35, 0.50, 0.65, 0.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)

        gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: -width, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        // Create CA animation that will move mask from outside bounds left to outside bounds right
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.x")
        animation.byValue = width * 2
        // How long it takes for glare to move across button
        animation.duration = 3
        // Repeat forever
        animation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        layer.addSublayer(shineLayer)
        shineLayer.mask = gradientLayer

        // Add animation
        gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: "shine")
    }

    func stopFlash() {
        // Search all sublayer masks for "shine" animation and remove
        layer.sublayers?.forEach {
            $0.mask?.removeAnimation(forKey: "shine")
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    // Helper to snapshot a view
    var snapshot: UIImage? {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size)

        let image = renderer.image { context in
            layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
        return image
    }
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        button.setTitle("My Special Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
        button.sizeToFit()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior == .never
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        button.flash()
    }

    @objc func didPressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.stopFlash()
    }
}
```

You should get an effect like so:

[image: button with glare effect]